# 6 Week 7 Day Ranges for Each Month for SSRS Calendar

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, calendar, reportbuilder3.0

I have a monthly calendar in SSRS that pulls in all the days of a month you specify and also shows days from the previous and next month in order to show 6, 7 day weeks. What I'm trying to do now is display the ranges for each week for a month, for example, in November 2015 I would want:

```
Oct 25-31
Nov 1-7
Nov 8-14
Nov 15-21
Nov 22-28
Nov 29-Dec 5
```

The expression I'm trying to set up to leverage looks like the following:

```
="Week " & VBCRLF & Left(MonthName(Parameters!start_cymd.Value.Month,False),3) & " " & Fields!Day.Value & " - " & Fields!Day.Value + 6
```

What road should I go down in terms of adding to this expression to get my desired output? If you need more information to answer my question, I'd be happy to provide it. Thanks!

**Edit:**

Current Output
[image]

Stored Proc Generating Calendar:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Event].[Report_Event_Calendar_Month_sp]
@start_cymd DATE = NULL
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @StartDate DATE = @start_cymd ,
        @EndDate DATE = @start_cymd ,
        @SDate DATE = @start_cymd

---First day of current month 
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(s, 0, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @StartDate), 0))
SET @SDate = DATEADD(s, 0, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @SDate), 0))
---First day to display on calendar
SET @StartDate =  DATEADD(DAY, -DATEPART(DAY, @StartDate) - 6, @StartDate)
---Last day of month
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @SDate) + 1, 0))
---Last day to display on calendar
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(DAY, -DATEPART(DAY, @EndDate) + 35, @EndDate)

;WITH Dates([Date])
      AS (
            SELECT @StartDate AS [Date]
            UNION ALL
            SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date])
            FROM Dates
            WHERE [Date] < @EndDate
          ) ,
      Events
      AS (
            SELECT EventDesc ,
                   Notes ,
                   start_cymd AS EventDate ,
                   MemberName
            FROM   [Event].Event_Description ED
                   INNER JOIN [Event].SQL_Team_Events SE ON ED.EventDesc_ID = SE.EventDesc_ID
                   INNER JOIN [Event].SQL_Team_Member SM ON SE.Event_ID = SM.Event_ID
                   INNER JOIN [Event].Members M ON SM.Member_ID = M.Member_ID
         )


---Number the records based on the date, if multiple records have 
   ---the same date then they will be numbered the same. Used in 
   ---calculation to determine row record is to display 
    SELECT   [Order] = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY d.[Date]) ,
   ---Date used in all calculations for date
             d.[Date] ,
   ---Generates matrix columns
             [WeekDay] = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, d.[Date]) ,
   ---Used to display day of month on calendar
             [Day] = DATEPART(DAY, d.[Date]) ,
   ---Used in some calculations for display
             [Month] = DATEPART(MONTH, d.[Date]) ,
             e.EventDesc ,
             e.Notes ,
             e.EventDate ,
             e.MemberName
    FROM     Dates d
             LEFT JOIN Events e ON d.[Date] = e.EventDate
   ---Set the maximum number of times the CTE 'Dates' can recurse
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 100)

END
GO
```

Comment: You'll want an `IIF` function at the end of your expression that determines if `Fields!Day.Value + 6` exceeds the length of your month to get the mid-week month change shown correctly (*Nov 29-Sep 5*). At a first glance, the rest seems fine to me.

Comment: Yes...coffee hasn't kicked in yet lol.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't able to use a SQL Query to generate this information in a dataset?  It strikes me that would be considerably easier, especially when you consider the varying month lengths you will have to deal with

Comment: Added current output and proc used to generate calendar above

Comment: Try this..http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=jtqbvd&s=9#.VjjfPdWrSUk

Comment: Did you try the suggestion commented by @Oceans? We will assist you with the expression. I faced a similar requeriment I'll look for the expression used in that case.

Comment: Yeah I am, but accounting for everything in it is going to be extremely difficult, but not impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**Reporting Services Expression**

```
=Switch(
DatePart("D",Fields!Date.Value) + 6 > Datepart("D",Fields!Date.Value.AddDays(1-Fields!Date.Value.Day).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)),
"Week" & VBCRLF & Left(MonthName(Fields!Date.Value.Month,False),3) & " " & DatePart("D",Fields!Date.Value) & " - " &
Left(MonthName(Fields!Date.Value.Month + 1,False),3) & " " & DatePart("D",Fields!Date.Value.AddDays(6)),
true,
"Week" & VBCRLF & Left(MonthName(Fields!Date.Value.Month,False),3) & " " & DatePart("D",Fields!Date.Value) & " - " &
DatePart("D",Fields!Date.Value.AddDays(6))
)
```

- Tested with 2015-02-27 returned: `Week feb 27 - mar 5`
- Tested with 2015-11-29 returned: `Week nov 29 - dec 5`
- Tested with 2015-11-22 returned: `Week nov 22 - 22`

> Note I am using the field `Date` of your dataset intead of `Day`

**T-SQL**

At T-SQL level you can add the columns with the data you need, then concatenate those columns in the report expression.

```
SELECT   [Order] = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY d.[Date]) ,
---Date used in all calculations for date
            d.[Date] ,
---Generates matrix columns
            [WeekDay] = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, d.[Date]) ,
---Used to display day of month on calendar
            [Day] = DATEPART(DAY, d.[Date]) ,
---Used in some calculations for display
            [Month] = DATEPART(MONTH, d.[Date])
---New filds for rows expression in SSRS
            ,LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,d.[Date]),3) as [StartMonth]
            ,DATEPART(DAY,d.[Date]) as [StartDay]
            ,IIF(DATEADD(day,6,d.[Date]) > EOMONTH(d.[Date])
                ,LEFT(DateName(Month,DATEADD(day,6,d.[Date])),3)
                ,''
                ) as [EndMonth]
            ,Datepart(day,DATEADD(day,6,d.[Date])) as [EndMonth]            
            e.EventDesc ,
            e.Notes ,
            e.EventDate ,
            e.MemberName
FROM     Dates d
            LEFT JOIN Events e ON d.[Date] = e.EventDate
```

Expression:

```
= "Week" & VBCRLF & Fields!StartMonth.Value & " " & Fields!StartDay.Value &
" - " & Fields!EndMonth.Value & " " & Fields!EndDay.Value
```

Let me know if this can help you.

Comment: This was perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: @postald, Nice! you can select my answer as correct if your question was cleared, just click to the correct symbol in the left side of my answer.